# Trying to load images after scrolling to that area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load images after scrolling to that div.There are multiple images in that div but first images is being loaded to every `img scr`

here is an example:

```
<div>
   <img src="preload.jpg" data-src="img1.png" data-rel="preload" /> 
   <img src="preload.jpg" data-src="img2.png" data-rel="preload" /> 
   <img src="preload.jpg" data-src="img3.png" data-rel="preload" /> 
   <img src="preload.jpg" data-src="img4.png" data-rel="preload" /> 
   <img src="preload.jpg" data-src="img5.png" data-rel="preload" /> 
</div>
```

### And the jquery i am trying:

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {

    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}
var imgSet = false;
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if(isElementInViewport(jQuery('img[data-rel="preload"]'))){
        var toload = jQuery('img[data-rel="preload"]');
        if(!imgSet){
            toload.each(function(){
                var img = toload.attr('data-src');
                toload.attr('src', img);
                imgSet = true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But problem is that `img1.png` is being loaded in every `src` attribute on `img`

Comment: your `each` function does not care about the current item, i guess that's why... and watch out, `jQuery('img[data-rel="preload"]')` probably returns several elements in an array, but your code is not very clear whether you use it as one element or an array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery each function have to take as param the actual item of the iterator, try to change it like this:

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if(isElementInViewport(jQuery('img[data-rel="preload"]'))){
        var toload = jQuery('img[data-rel="preload"]');

            toload.each(function(index) {
                if ($(this).visible(true)) {
                   var img = $(this).attr('data-src'); // $(this) is actual image in loop
                   $(this).attr('src', img);
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay but it loads images on every `img src` when the first item is in viewport and last item not yet has come into viewport

Comment: Ok, I'm going to update my answer,you should check if item is 'visible', with $(item).visible property, let me know if this fits your request.

Comment: I've deleted imgSet flag, it' won't be necessary